# Unable to use graphEdg

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Graph API and want to access Media Url of all Instagram business account posts 
But I am unable to use graphEdge and without using graphEdge I can't get all URLs means not able to use paginations

I have Done this with Graph Node but Response is with Protected items of pagination that are unable to get

```
 try {
            // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object0
            $response = $fb->get(
                '/' . $instagram_account_id . '?fields=media',
                $_SESSION[accounts][fbusers][0]->access_token
            );
        } catch (FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch (FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

When I use Graph Edge return error 
"Unable to convert the response from Graph to a GraphEdge because the response does not look like a GraphEdge."

Answer (score 0):

To get the media URLs of all posts by an Instagram business account, one can use this call:

```
<INSTAGRAM_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID>/media?fields=media_url
```

[Here's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/) some documentation